# What is the fastest way to generate a long random string in Go?

Tags: string, random, go

Like [a-zA-Z0-9] string:

*na1dopW129T0anN28udaZ*

or hexadecimal string:

*8c6f78ac23b4a7b8c0182d*

By long I mean 2K and more characters.

Comment: !why do you want a 2Kbyte random string? For cryptographic purposes a 1024 bits (i.e. 128 bytes) should be enough. And you'll have hard time to get really random 2048 bytes.

Comment: And what is the operating system? On Linux you could read from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`... http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/random.4.html

Comment: It is impossible to answer question without knowing the quality of required random numbers. So I assume it is not for the purpose of cryptography. Also I do not understand "fastest". I can imagine it could be some game but requirements for random string make look it as password. But again why performance is important.

Comment: May be our response is required for article in a blog )))

Comment: It's not for cryptography, it's for database workload generator.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This does about 200MBps on my box.  There's obvious room for improvement.

```
type randomDataMaker struct {
    src rand.Source
}

func (r *randomDataMaker) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    for i := range p {
        p[i] = byte(r.src.Int63() & 0xff)
    }
    return len(p), nil
}
```

You'd just use `io.CopyN` to produce the string you want.  Obviously you could adjust the character set on the way in or whatever.

The nice thing about this model is that it's just an `io.Reader` so you can use it making anything.

Test is below:

```
func BenchmarkRandomDataMaker(b *testing.B) {
    randomSrc := randomDataMaker{rand.NewSource(1028890720402726901)}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        b.SetBytes(int64(i))
        _, err := io.CopyN(ioutil.Discard, &randomSrc, int64(i))
        if err != nil {
            b.Fatalf("Error copying at %v: %v", i, err)
        }
    }
}
```

On one core of my 2.2GHz i7:

```
BenchmarkRandomDataMaker       50000        246512 ns/op     202.83 MB/s
```

**EDIT**

Since I wrote the benchmark, I figured I'd do the obvious improvement thing (call out to the random less frequently).  With 1/8 the calls to rand, it runs about 4x faster, though it's a big uglier:

New version:

```
func (r *randomDataMaker) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    todo := len(p)
    offset := 0
    for {
        val := int64(r.src.Int63())
        for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
            p[offset] = byte(val & 0xff)
            todo--
            if todo == 0 {
                return len(p), nil
            }
            offset++
            val >>= 8
        }
    }

    panic("unreachable")
}
```

New benchmark:

```
BenchmarkRandomDataMaker      200000        251148 ns/op     796.34 MB/s
```

**EDIT 2**

Took out the masking in the cast to byte since it was redundant.  Got a good deal faster:

```
BenchmarkRandomDataMaker      200000        231843 ns/op     862.64 MB/s
```

(this is so much easier than real work *sigh*)

**EDIT 3**

This came up in irc today, so I released a library.  Also, my actual benchmark tool, while useful for relative speed, isn't sufficiently accurate in its reporting.

I created [randbo](https://github.com/dustin/randbo) that you can reuse to produce random streams wherever you may need them.

Comment: But since it's int63 there's an always-off bit in every 8th byte, right?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the Go package [uniuri](https://github.com/dchest/uniuri) to generate random strings (or view the source code to see how they're doing it).  You'll want to use:

```
func NewLen(length int) string
```

> NewLen returns a new random string of the provided length, consisting of standard characters.

Or, to specify the set of characters used:

```
func NewLenChars(length int, chars []byte) string
```

Answer (score 17):

This is actually a little biased towards the first 8 characters in the set (since 255 is not a multiple of `len(alphanum)`), but this will get you most of the way there.

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"
)

func randString(n int) string {
    const alphanum = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    var bytes = make([]byte, n)
    rand.Read(bytes)
    for i, b := range bytes {
        bytes[i] = alphanum[b % byte(len(alphanum))]
    }
    return string(bytes)
}
```

Comment: The core crypto/rand.Reader does < 30MBps on my box.

Comment: True, the question didn't specify whether the strings have to be cryptographically random. If they don't, your solution's probably better.

Comment: I've come across this great answer several times and used it each time.  Here's another possible way of generating strings: http://play.golang.org/p/1GwSRsKIsd

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate cryptographically secure random string, I recommend you to take a look at [this page](https://elithrar.github.io/article/generating-secure-random-numbers-crypto-rand/). Here is a helper function that reads `n` random bytes from the source of randomness of your OS and then use these bytes to base64encode it. Note that the string length would be bigger than `n` because of base64.

```
package main

import(
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func GenerateRandomBytes(n int) ([]byte, error) {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    _, err := rand.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return b, nil
}

func GenerateRandomString(s int) (string, error) {
    b, err := GenerateRandomBytes(s)
    return base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(b), err
}

func main() {
    token, _ := GenerateRandomString(32)
    fmt.Println(token)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here Evan Shaw's answer re-worked without the bias towards the first 8 characters of the string.  Note that it uses lots of expensive `big.Int` operations so probably isn't that quick!  The answer is crypto strong though.

It uses `rand.Int` to make an integer of exactly the right size `len(alphanum) ** n`, then does what is effectively a base conversion into base `len(alphanum)`.

There is almost certainly a better algorithm for this which would involve keeping a much smaller remainder and adding random bytes to it as necessary.  This would get rid of the expensive long integer arithmetic.

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func randString(n int) string {
    const alphanum = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    symbols := big.NewInt(int64(len(alphanum)))
    states := big.NewInt(0)
    states.Exp(symbols, big.NewInt(int64(n)), nil)
    r, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, states)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var bytes = make([]byte, n)
    r2 := big.NewInt(0)
    symbol := big.NewInt(0)
    for i := range bytes {
        r2.DivMod(r, symbols, symbol)
        r, r2 = r2, r
        bytes[i] = alphanum[symbol.Int64()]
    }
    return string(bytes)
}
```

Comment: Why does everyone think about cryptography? The key criteria is speed not security.

Comment: At the point where you introduce crypto/rand.Reader, it's going to do fewer than 30MBps (on my box) vs. over 800MBps.