# rand.Prime(rand.Reader, 3072) takes a long time to execute

Tags: go

I implemented RSA as an example.  Several weeks ago, it seemed to work fine.

Now, however, the generation of keys takes a long time (>10 seconds).  I've narrowed it down to the line:

```
import "crypto/rand"

p, _ := rand.Prime(rand.Reader, 3072)
```

Why would this take a significant amount of time?

Comment: Why? How long do you think it should take? Probabilistic primality tests like Miller-Rabin have to perform many bignumber modular exponentiations. It is very expensive, and the distribution of primes means that sometimes it will quickly find a prime and sometimes it takes much longer.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the computational cost of doing primality testing, according to the [`crypto/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/) documentation, the numbers are sourced from a "cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator".  Such sources of randomness [might be slow](http://drsnyder.us/2014/04/16/linux-dev-urandom-and-concurrency.html), depending on your environment.

That's probably why `crypto/prime` consumes an `io.Reader`, so that we can feed it another source of randomness.  [e.g.](http://play.golang.org/p/a_LTLFz35m):

```
package main

import (
    cRand "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    mRand "math/rand"
)

// Adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771930/
type randReader struct {
    src mRand.Source
}

func newRandReader() *randReader {
    // FIXME: source the seed from crypto/rand instead.
    return &randReader{mRand.NewSource(42)}
}

func (r *randReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    for i := range p {
        p[i] = byte(r.src.Int63() & 0xff)
    }
    return len(p), nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    r := newRandReader()
    p, _ := cRand.Prime(r, 300)
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

Even with this, trying to generate 3000-bit primes does appear to be inherently slow (takes several seconds on my machine too) due to the cost of primality testing, as James K Polk suggests.